# BitLocker- Used Space Only to Entire Drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

I currently have an external hard drive that I encrypted via BitLocker with the 'encrypt used space only' option some time ago.

I'd like to change that- I want to encrypt the entire hard drive, including the free space.

The only way I've been able to figure out is to disable/decrypt the hard drive, then encrypt it again. I'd like to avoid this.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I just edited it- hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: Yes;  If you want to encrypt the free space you would need to repeat the process.